# Python - to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am currently trying to write a dataframe to a csv using to_csv. The input and output for the data is below. How do I write the to_csv to ensure that the fields with commas still get double quoted but the row with Katie doesn't get additional double quotes?

Input:

```
Title  
Johnny,Appleseed  
Lauren,Appleseed  
Katie_"Appleseed"
```

Output:

```
Title  
"Johnny,Appleseed"  
"Lauren,Appleseed"  
Katie_""Appleseed""
```

code

```
df.to_csv(r"filelocation", sep=',')
```

Comment: The CSV encoders generally are smart enough to handle random garbage, are they positively not working for you? Post your "input" as a more logical table (unless the strings on each line are just that); not sure how it correlates to the dataframe that Pandas has

Comment: its escaping the quotes found in `Katie_"Appleseed"`, why do you want to prevent this?

Comment: @HaleemurAli I want to prevent this because the csv is then going into a table and I need to preserve the raw format of it without changed the name of the text

Comment: ah, then as @AntonvBR suggests, just use a different quote char. But escaping the quote char is standard behavior in delimited text files.

Comment: @AntonvBR If I utilize `quotechar="'"` then the file will not have double quotes around the separator which is the comma

Comment: @AntonvBR I'm talking about the second and third row

Comment: @jumpman23 sorry but still makes no sense to me.

Comment: @AntonvBR I believe Arnon answered my question below that they must be escaped but I need to be able to preserve my initial title while copying this data into Redshift.

Comment: [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) has an argument `doublequote` that defaults to `True` which controls quoting of quotechar inside a field.  To achieve what you want try adding argument `doublequote=False`.  Note though that your resulting csv file will be quite odd in that a single quote can sometimes be ambiguous.  (Consider if you had a field that started and ended with quotes as part of the data. The quotes would be stripped the next time the csv is read.)

Comment: Amazon Redshift docs [has examples showing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#load-from-csv) that it has no problems with the doubled double quote.  I think you're trying to solve a problem that you don't need to solve.

Comment: Yes. Arnon had it right. I just kept the double-quoting and added `CSV QUOTE '\"'` into my copy command and got it working. Thanks all!

Comment: Read those docs again.  You can leave out the `QUOTE '\"'` and just leave `CSV`.  Read those Amazon Redshift docs on `copy` when using the [`CSV`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv) parameter.  Key part: "QUOTE [AS] 'quote_character'
Optional. Specifies the character to be used as the quote character when using the CSV parameter. **The default is a double quotation mark ( " ).**"  (Bold mine.)  In other words you don't need to define the quote character because you're already using the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping quotes with double quotes is part of [the CSV standard:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

> "7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote."